# Absolute Continuity and $\sigma$-finiteness

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be an arbitrary measurable space, and let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two measures defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that $\nu<<\mu$. Given that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, can we conclude that $\nu$ has to be $\sigma$-finite?

If so, can someone please provide a rigorous proof of the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't conclude this. Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue-measure and $\nu$ be the measure with Lebesgue-density equal to $\infty$, i.e. $\nu(A) = \begin{cases} 0 & \lambda(A) = 0 \\ \infty & \text{else}\end{cases}$.

Now the only sets that are finite with respect to $\nu$ are Lebesgue-nullsets. But a countable union of nullsets is still a nullset, so you can't fill $\mathbb{R}$ with sets of finite measure.

Comment: Just to complete the argument formally, if we suppose that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then there exists a partition $\{\Omega_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\nu(\Omega)=\infty$ and $\nu(\Omega_{k})=0$ for all $k\geq 1$. On the other hand, by the countable additivity of $\nu$, we get $\nu(\Omega)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\nu(\Omega_{k})=0$. This is a contradiction.

Am I correct in putting across the argument?

Comment: This is essentially correct. The decomposition must fulfill $\nu(\Omega_k) < \infty$ for all $k$, but the only sets of finite measure wrt. $\nu$ are nullsets, so $\nu(\Omega_k) = 0$.

Comment: That's right. I directly wrote $0$ instead of $<\infty$. Thank you so much.